# Command Line Batch Runs on Linux

Tags: repast-simphony

On the Windows installation of Repast Simphony 2.7 there exists the `batch_runner.jar` in the installation directory, while on Ubuntu it seems to be missing.
I try to execute batch runs without a GUI inside a docker container.
Is there a way to import/build the `batch_runner.jar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the windows batch_runner.jar that should work on Linux. If not please, reply.

Comment: I do have a Windows system and access to the batch_runner.jar.  Putting the JAR-File on the same level as the eclipse folder creates the error `Error: Unable to initialize main class repast.simphony.batch.standalone.StandAloneMain
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLineParser`. This package is missing in the plugins folder, but even after manually inserting the Apache Commons cli Jar, the same error raises

Comment: I found a temporary "solution" by copying the `plugins` folder from windows to the linux system.